# Printing in input

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a problem to calculate when the user enters the date of the birthday to see how much is left to the next and that the result is written in input. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function calcform(){
    with (document.form1) {
    var today = new Date();
    var fullyear = today.getFullYear();
    var future = new Date(+number1.value+ fullyear);
    var diff = future.getTime() - today.getTime();
    var days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ));
    }
  }
</script>
<form name="form1" action="">
    Type your date birth:
    <input type="text" id="number1" value="" size="30" /><br/>
    <p>
    Number of days until your birthday:
    <input type="text" id="result" value="" size="13" /><br/>
    <p>
    <input type="button" id="Calculate" value="Calculate" onclick="calcform()" />
    <input type="reset" value="Clear"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Take the plus sign out of the line var future before number1.value

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, you need to increment the date until the next birthday is greater than the current date, then measure the days.

```
function calcform(){
    var today = new Date();
    var fullyear = today.getFullYear();
    var future = new Date(document.getElementById('number1').value);
    future.setFullYear(fullyear);
    if(future.getTime()<today.getTime()) future.setFullYear(fullyear+1);
    var diff = future.getTime() - today.getTime();
    var days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ));
    document.getElementById('result').value=days;
}
```

Comment: Something is wrong with the function. When entering the date dd / mm / yyyy I dont get the exact number of days?